# Problem with MTP device

Tags: mp3, mtp

World.

How may I connect a MTP device on Ubuntu 12.04?

When I try to connect to transfer some music, an error message appears on the display. (was not possible to mount the device)

My phone has the Android 4.

Since now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the software to use mtp devices.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mtpfs mtp-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

Install gvfs-backends. This is a user space which helps to mount file systems like afc, afp, archive, ftp, mtp etc.